# $(window).scroll(function { } is not working in chrome (responsive)

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to animate elements on scroll. I used $(window).scroll(function{}
This is working fine with firefox (desktop and mobile view) but its not working with chrome on mobile device width. Can anybody help?
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var freetogo = false;
      var fadeshield = true;

      $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

            var div6 = $("#slide-9").offset().top;
            var ColorSwingOffset = $("#slide-12").offset().top;
            var pencils = $("#slide-6").offset().top;
            //var shieldSlideoffset=$("#slide-14").offset().top;


            if (ColorSwingOffset == scroll) {

              $(".color-pieces img").each(function() {
                $(this).posterSwing();
              });
            }

            var slidetransform = $("#slides")[0].style.transform.split(/[()]/);
            var translateX = slidetransform[1].split(',')[0];
            var translateY = slidetransform[1].split(',')[1];
            //console.log("translateY "+parseInt(translateY)+"translateX "+translateX);
            if (translateX == '-350%') {

              if ($('#slide-14 .slidepoints img').is(":hidden")) {
                $("#slide-14 .slidepoints img").fadeIn(1000);
                fadeshield = false;

              }


            }
```

Comment: Did you try remote debugging https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging ? Can you tell what happens when you scroll on chrome mobile ?